# Using foldl, write a function that converts a list of integers to an integer number?

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, foldleft

I'm trying to write a function `dec2int` that converts a list of integers to an integer number. My only constraint is that I must use `foldl`.

The type signature for the function is:

```
dec2int :: [Int] -> Int
```

The function should work in this way:

```
Input:  dec2int [2,3,4,5]
Output: 2345
```

I found a working solution here that I understand:

```
dec2int' = foldl (\x y -> 10*x +y) 0
```

I tried to write my own solution, using `foldl` as required:

```
dec2int xs = foldl (\a b -> a + (b*(10^(l-1)))) 0 xs
                  where l = length xs
```

However, I get this error:

```
ghci> dec2int [1,1]
20
```

I realised the value of `length xs` must be constant. However, I want the value to vary for my function.

I wanted to function to work in this way

```
0 + 1*10^((length [1,1])-1) = 10 = v
10 + 1 *10^((length [1])-1) = 11
```

How do I refer to the list during the recursion? I want the value of `length xs` to change each time `foldl` is called recursively?

Comment: The `dec2int' = foldl (\x y -> 10*x +y) 0` looks like the only simple solution. By working with powers we need to work with an index, and will make the function less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of the index in the step function of the fold:

```hs
dec2int xs = snd $ foldl (\(i, a) b -> (i + 1, a + b * 10 ^ (l - i))) (1, 0) xs
  where l = length xs
```

But, as Willem van Onsem says, this is more complicated than it needs to be.